# How to set default grub configuration file

Tags: linux, grub

I am booting four operating systems: Windows 7, Ubuntu, Kali Linux, and Linux Mint.  They were installed in that order, with Linux Mint most recently and Windows 7 first.  I am able to edit the /etc/default/grub file and update grub with `sudo update-grub`, but only configurations saved in the config file for Linux Mint are used.  Is there a way to specify which configuration file grub uses or a way to set the default?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: When your system boots, it runs a boot loader which used to be started from the master boot record (MBR) on the first sector of the boot partition. Newer systems do the same sort of thing, but a bit more convoluted (UEFI) that I don't understand yet.

The point is that the boot process decides what happens and which menu system - like grub to load. That's where the problem needs to be fixed.

I don't know how UEFI systems handle this, but it may still be able to be fixed the same way.

On the distro of your choice, install grub-customizer and run it.

You can get it from [here](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) for Ubuntu.

(You don't actually need this package, but I don't know how to do it manually without it.)

When it finishes reading all the grub stuff, you should see a menu of all your partitions and how they are configured to boot. Make sure it looks the way you want it to and edit it if necessary then save it.

So far, this is the same as what you have done manually.

Select File->Install to MBR (or whatever it says on UEFI systems). This will make sure the boot process uses the version of grub you just edited.

Now, hopefully, everything works fine. But ...

Later, when you run kernel updates in one of your other distros, the grub file that distro uses will be the one that gets updated - not necessarily your preferred one and, in some circumstances, the boot loader may get rewritten too.

If that happens, just reboot into your preferred distribution and do this whole procedure again. Grub-customizer will find the updates made by the other distros and incorporate them into the new menu.

One thing to watch out for is that when you delete old kernels, make sure to run grub-customizer or update things manually from your preferred distro. If you don't do that the preferred grub menu can get outdated and point to deleted kernels.